# Dojo DnD delete selected items

Tags: drag-and-drop, dojo

Is there a way to delete selected items from a dojo DnD Source by dragging them out their container, or by pressing DEL key? I tried to achieve this by adding a dojo.connect->onkeypress but It seems Source doesn't listen to this events.

...
In response to Rodrigo Quiñones [I've created a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ascke/xLchmz40/16/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xLchmz40)

```
//[...]
on(dom.byId('sortByItems'), 'keypress', function(evt) {
   if (evt.charOrCode == keys.DELETE)
       console.log('User wants to unselect:', sortByDnDTarget.getSelectedNodes());
});

//[...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off; The dndSource does no listen to keypress events. I believe it never gains 'focus', only items contained in it can get focused. It does however listen to things like 'click' etc.

Secondly, DELETE key is not captured in the `keypressed` event handler, since this is designed only to capture printable stuff, so `<enter>`, `<del>` and `<esc>` etc. does not apply for that event.

Instead use `keyup` or `keydown` listeners - and apply them on `window`

The following snippet should do what youre aiming for:

```
sortByDnDTarget.getSelectedNodes().forEach(function(li) {
    sortByDnDTarget.delItem(sortByDnDTarget.getItem(li.id));
});
```

Comment: You're right. Couldn't get a keypressed event handler over a DnDSource. That approach with the "forEach..." sounds razonable, but I still need a kind of control on where the user press the DEL key.
Seems that I should consider to not use keyboard to delete elements from the list. Instead of that, try to find a way to remove the items by dragging them out of such list. Thanks.

Comment: It is common to have a 'remove' button besides a selection list like that, maybe thats your out. Problem is, if you do `window.onkeyup ... key == keys.DELETE ...`, this event is caught from any situation. For instance if your user is trying to delete text he wrote in an input field

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought, mschr. Maybe this DnD lists is not the right approach for resolve my problem. Thanks.